# How to configure gpg2 to pass smartcard PIN unless pinentry programm?

Tags: gpg

My configuration:

- Centos 6.5
- gnugp2-2.0.14-6.el6_4.x86_64
- gnupg2-smime-2.0.14-6.el6_4.x86_64

I configured `gpg2` to use my signature key in smartcard gnupg V2.0.
I imported my gpg signature key to the rpm store.

I need to sign an rpm package using `rpm --addsign myApp.rpm`.

It works fine, but `rpm` prompts once for the smartcard PIN, and `gpg2` (with `pinentry` programm) prompts three times for the smartcard PIN.

I expected that `rpm --addsign` passes the PIN (get in first prompt) to `gpg2` and `gpg2` doesn't ask again for the PIN.

Is it possible to have only *one* prompt to sign the rpm package with `gpg2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the pin to be cached you need to run `gpg-agent` and your card should **not** have the `forcesig` bit set.

AFAIK, by default, the cards are shipped with the forcesig bit set, which is more secure. You can see this using the `gpg --card-edit command` and look for the entry Signature PIN. According to the manual:

> Signature PIN
>
> When set to "forced", gpg requests the entry of a PIN for each signature operation. When set to "non forced", gpg may cache the PIN as long as the card has not been removed from the reader.

You can change the bit by using:

```
$ gpg --card-edit
....
gpg: detected reader `MSI StarReader SMART [Smart Card Reader Interface]'
Version ..........: 2.0
Manufacturer .....: ZeitControl
Serial number ....: 0000201C
Name of cardholder: Anthony van der Neut
Language prefs ...: en
Sex ..............: please
URL of public key : http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/publickey.asc
Login data .......: anthon
Private DO 1 .....: [not set]
Private DO 2 .....: [not set]
Signature PIN ....: forced           <<<<< this is what should not be 'forced'
Key attributes ...: 2048R 2048R 2048R
Max. PIN lengths .: 32 32 32
PIN retry counter : 3 0 3
Signature counter : 2
....
gpg/card > admin
gpg/card > forcesig
```

(Shameless plug: for more details on securely setting up a card, see my rant [gemini://ruamel.eu/rants/2014/setting_up_an_openpgp_smartcard_with_gnupg.gmi](https://portal.mozz.us/gemini/ruamel.eu/rants/2014/setting_up_an_openpgp_smartcard_with_gnupg.gmi)

Comment: @usergfo Are you going to post the other question (from your answer now deleted by the moderators)?

Comment: Yes, i will be create a new thread soon.

Comment: Your rant isn't available any longer.

Comment: @Nate-Wilkins my (paid) provider of 30 years (xs4all.nl) decided to stop ssh access to account without notification. I'll see if I can set up an new website and update the rant link. (or send me an email and I'll send the doc in reply)

Comment: @Nate-Wilkins I put the rant up on my gemini server. Do remember it is 8 years old and things have changed.