# How close smartcard after sign rpm with GPG2?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

Adding to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141569/72471):

How do I close gnupg V2.0 smartcard after signing an rpm?

I tried to execute:

```
gpg-agent --default-cache-ttl 15 --max-cache-ttl 15 --daemon
```

But after 15 seconds, if I execute again a signature, `gpg2` doesn't prompt for the PIN.

The only solution I've found so far, is to unplug/plug smartcard on the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting `gpg-agent` with those parameters probably gives you a message:

```
gpg-agent: gpg-agent running and available
```

You are not changing that running session, and that is what caches your PIN.
That session is (at least on my Ubuntu 12.04 system) started by the gnome-session, effectively by the script `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent`. On my system it doesn't seem that that file allows for any dynamic commandline option setting for `gpg-agent`, so you might have to hardcode those options in there.

You can of course also kill and restart the `gpg-agent`, that will let you get rid of the cached pins as well. Just make sure the output of the command goes to the file where the original invocation of `gpg-agent` puts it (on my system `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent-info-<hostname>`).

At some point my bank's software forced me to take out the smartcard, as a protective measure, after providing my signature/pin. As their software was running on a VirtualMachine, I would just temporarily virtually remove the USB (on which the CardReader was connected) from the host (using a small python script). That would work for you as well if you would be running on a VM.

Comment: It's only for my test that i run gpg-agent manualy. I have a client VM, but the reader is plugged on esx-server on closed room.

Comment: @usergfo If you run the gpg-agent manually, than you should just stop (`killall -SIGHUP gpg-agent`) and restart. I would not know how you can do the Python-disconnect-virtual USB trick on the ESX host.

Comment: Thanks for yor help. It work fine. I have only 1 prompt per RPM signature.

Comment: @usergfo Can you accept and/or vote on the answers I gave if appropriate, then others don't have read through the comments to see if an answer is appropriate (and I get some reputation increase ;-) )